# Dependency property (of an attached behavior) is not being updated by an attached property (of another attached behavior)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

WPF.

In XAML, I have a Canvas which will hold TextBlocks whose placement is determined by information gathered from a RichTextBox control. Both the Canvas and the RichTextBox have attached behaviors which add the "Outline" property.

My goal is to have the RichTextBox set the outline property from its  RichTextBoxSelectionChanged event. The outline property will be constantly changing as text is entered into the RichTextBox.

I need the "OutlineCanvas" to pick up the change in the Outline property and act upon it by placing TextBlocks in the assoicated Canvas.

For reasons I can't get, the below code DOES set the "Outline" in the RichTextBox, but it is NOT being picked up by the OutlineCanvas.

It does seem as though the behavior for the OutlineCanvas is initiated ONCE, but it does not pickup the Outline being set in the RichTextBox behavior.

Where am I going wrong? How should this be done?

TIA

```
XAML
<Canvas Grid.Column="0" Name="OutlineCanvas" Background="Azure" >
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <b:OutlineBehavior Outline="{Binding ElementName=RichTextControl, Path=(b:RichTextBehavior.Outline)}"/> 
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Canvas>

  <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextControl" Grid.Column="1"
                               a:SmartAdorner.Visible="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.IsAdornerVisible}"
                                Panel.ZIndex="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.ZIndex}"  Cursor="IBeam"                               
                                Height="{Binding VirtualPage.Height}" 
                                Visibility="{Binding Path=TranscriptionLayer.Visibility}"  
                             SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" 
                             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                             AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"
                            >

 <i:Interaction.Behaviors>    
                        <b:RichTextBehavior 
                                SelectedText="{Binding  TranscriptionLayer.SelectedText}"                              
                                Image="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.Image}"
                                MoveImage="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.MoveImage}"
                                DeleteImage="{Binding TranscriptionLayer.DeleteImage}"
                            />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>



C#
public class OutlineBehavior : Behavior<Canvas>
    {
        // The XAML attaches the behavior when it is instantiated.
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
        }



        public static ProgressNoteOutline GetOutline(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ProgressNoteOutline)obj.GetValue(OutlineProperty);
        }

        public static void SetOutline(DependencyObject obj, ProgressNoteOutline value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(OutlineProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Outline.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Outline", typeof(ProgressNoteOutline), typeof(OutlineBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnOutlineChanged));

        private static void OnOutlineChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OutlineBehavior behavior = d as OutlineBehavior;
            if (behavior == null)
                return;

            Canvas canv = behavior.AssociatedObject as Canvas;
            if (canv == null)
                return;

            ProgressNoteOutline _outline = (ProgressNoteOutline)e.NewValue;
            if (_outline == null)
                return;

            OutlineItem[] _items = _outline.items;
            foreach (OutlineItem t in _items)
            {
                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                tb.Background = Brushes.AntiqueWhite;
                tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
                tb.Inlines.Add(new Italic(new Bold(new Run(t.text))));

                Canvas.SetLeft(tb, 0);
                Canvas.SetTop(tb, t.Y);

                canv.Children.Add(tb);
            }

        }

The RichTextBox property (in its behavior):
 public ProgressNoteOutline Outline
        {
            get { return (ProgressNoteOutline)GetValue(OutlineProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OutlineProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Outline.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Outline", typeof(ProgressNoteOutline), typeof(RichTextBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ProgressNoteOutline());
```

Lastly, in the RichTextBox behavior, Outline is being set as:

```
 var _items = new OutlineItem[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                _items[i] = new OutlineItem { Y = i * 30, text = string.Format("Title {0}", i) };
            }
            Outline = new ProgressNoteOutline { items = _items };
```

Comment: tried setting Mode twoway in binding?

Comment: @WPFUser yes. Did not work.

Comment: can you post RichTextBoxBehavior code?

Comment: @WPFUser Sure...But it is fairly long and most of it is not pertinent to the problem at hand. If you're sure you want it, I'll be happy to post it, but I think I included the most important part in the Attached property declaration of the original post. :)

Comment: i was curious to know where it went wrong.. it seems you resolved with work-around,, cheers

Comment: @WPFUser For reasons I don't know,  when going from behavior to behavior, the target behavior of the OutlineCanvas was never being triggered -- no matter what syntax I used. To my simple way of thinking, it almost appears as if a behavior must connect to a concrete object, or concreate object to a behavior -- but not behavior to behavior (if that makes any sense?). I would sure appreciate input from somebody who knows this for a fact.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to get how this binding should work--from one behavior to another. So what does work was to subclass the canvas as:

```
    public class OutlineCanvas : Canvas
    {

        public ProgressNoteOutline Outline
        {
            get { return (ProgressNoteOutline)GetValue(OutlineProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OutlineProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Outline.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Outline", 
                typeof(ProgressNoteOutline), typeof(OutlineCanvas),
                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnOutlineChanged));

        private static void OnOutlineChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OutlineCanvas canv = d as OutlineCanvas;
            if (canv == null)
                return;           

            ProgressNoteOutline _outline = (ProgressNoteOutline)e.NewValue;
            if (_outline == null)
                return;

            OutlineItem[] _items = _outline.items;
            if (_items == null)
                return;

            foreach (OutlineItem t in _items)
            {
                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                tb.Background = Brushes.AntiqueWhite;
                tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
                tb.Inlines.Add(new Italic(new Bold(new Run(t.text))));

                SetLeft(tb, 0);
                SetTop(tb, t.Y);

                canv.Children.Add(tb);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then change the XAML as:

```
 <b:OutlineCanvas Grid.Column="0" x:Name="OutlineCanvas" Background="Azure" />

<b:RichTextBehavior               
       Outline="{Binding ElementName=OutlineCanvas, Path=Outline}" />
```

Hope it helps somebody :)